# Why are multiple imports from the Hyper crate failing?

Tags: rust, hyper

I'm working on a very simple HTTP client in Rust, built on top of the `hyper` ([GitHub](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper), [crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/hyper)) crate.

When I try to replicate the `examples/client.rs` file in a new Cargo project using `cargo build` (as well as using `rustc src/main.rs`), I get multiple errors caused by failed imports from `hyper`.

Here's the top of my `main.rs`:

```
extern crate hyper;

use hyper::client::{Client, Request, Response, DefaultTransport as HttpStream};
use hyper::header::Connection;
use hyper::{Decoder, Encoder, Next};
```

The rest of the file is, except for some comments, identical to the `examples/client.rs` file from the `hyper` repository.

At compile time, I get the following errors:

```
src/main.rs:10:48: 10:78 error: unresolved import `hyper::client::DefaultTransport`. There is no `DefaultTransport` in `hyper::client` [E0432]
src/main.rs:10 use hyper::client::{Client, Request, Response, DefaultTransport as HttpStream};
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:10:48: 10:78 help: run `rustc --explain E0432` to see a detailed explanation
src/main.rs:12:13: 12:20 error: unresolved import `hyper::Decoder`. There is no `Decoder` in `hyper` [E0432]
src/main.rs:12 use hyper::{Decoder, Encoder, Next};
                           ^~~~~~~
src/main.rs:12:13: 12:20 help: run `rustc --explain E0432` to see a detailed explanation
src/main.rs:12:22: 12:29 error: unresolved import `hyper::Encoder`. There is no `Encoder` in `hyper` [E0432]
src/main.rs:12 use hyper::{Decoder, Encoder, Next};
                                    ^~~~~~~
src/main.rs:12:22: 12:29 help: run `rustc --explain E0432` to see a detailed explanation
src/main.rs:12:31: 12:35 error: unresolved import `hyper::Next`. There is no `Next` in `hyper` [E0432]
src/main.rs:12 use hyper::{Decoder, Encoder, Next};
                                             ^~~~
src/main.rs:12:31: 12:35 help: run `rustc --explain E0432` to see a detailed explanation
src/main.rs:53:6: 53:40 error: trait `hyper::client::Handler` is not in scope [E0405]
src/main.rs:53 impl hyper::client::Handler<HttpStream> for Dump {
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:53:6: 53:40 help: run `rustc --explain E0405` to see a detailed explanation
src/main.rs:53:6: 53:40 help: you can to import it into scope: `use hyper::server::Handler;`.
```

In case it may contribute to this issue, here are the contents of my `Cargo.toml`:

```
name = "my_project"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = ["email@example.com"]

[dependencies]
getopts = "0.2"
hyper = "0.9.6"

[[bin]]
name = "my_project"
```

Some of the imports are actually working, so assuming the example in the repository is up to date, I really can't tell what's wrong. The source files of the crate look like they expose the involved types, but I'm very new to Rust so I may be misreading the files.

Comment: What version of hyper are you using?

Comment: @squiguy 0.9.6, the latest version available via crates.io.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using examples from the master branch that do not work with `0.9.6` version. You can take a look at examples on the branch [`0.9.6`](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/tree/v0.9.6) or make cargo use `hyper` direct from github, writing on `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]                                     
hyper = {git = "https://github.com/hyperium/hyper"}
```

Comment: Using the implementation from the `0.9.6` branch works. Thanks!